# Concurrent Refresh and Date Range selection making the Infinite Container show incorrect results

Tags: codenameone

I'm using infinite container to show the results based on date starting today's date. I have date range control added to the form and based on the selection container will update the results. I see issue sometimes when I select the date range and before it loads the container if I tries to swipe down the container will show incorrect results.

Example: I display date wise results starting 10/28, 10/29, 10/30, 10/31 etc.
When I do this container show 10/31 first and then display 10/28,  10/19, 10/30 and again 10/31(Twice). Is there any clue that can help me fix this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to return null. There is no place in your code where null is returned from fetch components. An empty array means there might still be more data pending in the future but null indicates the end of the data and you never return it in the code.

Comment: I'm returning null here in the code when index condition is not satified. else if (apps.length == 0) {
                            Component[] aa = null;
                            if (index <= 0) {
                                aa = new Component[]{new Label("No Appointments", "Header")};
                            }
                            return aa;
                        }

Comment: I suggest placing a debugger breakpoint on that `aa` entry to see if null is ever returned...

Comment: NULL is being returned when there are no records for the date I refer the control from here: range.https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/InfiniteContainer.html. I'm wondering is there any documentation that I can refer regarding this infinite container and where to return null and when fetchcomponents will called with index value etc..

Comment: There's the javadocs. You always return an array there. You return null when you no longer wish to scroll. Index is given when you scroll down and is reset if you pull to refresh